# Stuck with incrementing values in loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently, I was practising nested loops. I am stuck with iterating list of numbers and array elements.

Problem - I have an array which has 3 elements [A,B,C] and I want to add them to numbers from 1-100.

```
totalnum = 100
alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C']
length = len(alpha)
for i in range(1,totalnum):

    for j in range(length):

        result = i,alpha[j]
        break
    print(result)
```

I was planning to get output like:

```
(1, 'A')
(2, 'B')
(3, 'C')
(4, 'A')
(5, 'B')
(6, 'C')
```

Comment: 1) don't use `break`; 2) print out each `result` as soon as you create it. You're pretty close!

Comment: Also you may want to look into `from itertools import cycle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `break` is in the wrong spot.  That being said here a couple nicer ways to do it:

```
totalnum = 100
alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C']
length = len(alpha)
for i in range(1, totalnum + 1):
    print(i, alpha[i % len(alpha)])
```

or

```
from itertools import cycle
totalnum = 100
alpha = cycle(['A', 'B', 'C'])
length = len(alpha)
for i in range(1, totalnum + 1):
    print(i, next(alpha))
```

or (as pointed out by Patrick Haugh)

```
from itertools import cycle
for x in zip(range(1, 101), cycle('ABC')):
    print(x)
```

Comment: If you're already using itertools, your second example should definitely be `zip(range(1, 101), cycle('ABC'))`

Comment: Good point. I added that one as well, I left my `cycle` one just as a stepping stone to see how yours works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @HinaSatti Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it help :)

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse would love to vote but I can't because I am new :/

Comment: @Hina the check mark for answer is right below where you vote.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your first for loop so that it takes step sizes equal to the length of your alpha list, as well as changing `result = i,alpha[i]` to `result = i+j,alpha][i]`. Instead of breaking right away, append your result to a list, or print it right away.

```py
totalnum = 15
alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C']
length = len(alpha)
for i in range(1, totalnum, length):
    for j in range(length):
        result = i + j, alpha[j]
        print(result)
```

Output:

```
(1, 'A')
(2, 'B')
(3, 'C')
(4, 'A')
(5, 'B')
(6, 'C')
(7, 'A')
(8, 'B')
(9, 'C')
(10, 'A')
(11, 'B')
(12, 'C')
(13, 'A')
(14, 'B')
(15, 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `cycle`, as proposed in another answer, or imitate it using list comprehension:

```
[(i + 1, alpha[i % len(alpha)]) for i in range(totalnum)]
# [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'A'), (5, 'B'), (6, 'C')...]
```